# ID not generating after POST in explorer while using composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have installed a hyperledger network using composer in my system. Then I ran composer-rest-server over it. While POSTing in explorer I cant see any id field, in my JSON object. And thus there is no id returned after POST.[Reponse Screenhshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1SNJ.png)

Comment: What error are you seeing reported?  Can you provide an example of the Data that you are Posting that is causing the error?  Can you show the Model file you are using?

Comment: It is not an error. Ideally on POSTing something I should get id in response. Data is getting inserted via explorer but, id is not returned in response body.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a POST request for an Asset or a Participant, you specify an ID for your object as specified in the **identified by** field.  You manage the value of that ID.

If you submit a POST request for a Transaction, then you do get a `transactionId` returned in the HTTP response.

Comment: I have attached screeshot of POST reponse. Identified by field is buyerEmail. Which field in reponse is id ?

Comment: So in your model if you have "identified by buyerEmail" - then buyerEmail is the identifier (ID).